# featuredetection and measurements in x-ray image of solder joint

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection

I have a lot of pictures from a PCB taken with a X-Ray camera. I want to meassure the amount of solder in the holes. I thought about using python for that task as I am most familar with it. I have no idea where to start. I looked at openCV and scikit-image but am a little bit lost about how to approach my problem.

I attached a detail from one image where you can see one single joint. Every original picture has 8 of that joints. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRRxA.png)

I though about this workflow:

1. find the walls and upper/lower boundaries of the hole
2. fit a rectangle or even better a cylinder inside the boundaries
3. meassure the area of the rectangle/cylinder
4. find the solder in the hole
5. fit a rectangle or cylinder in the solder
6. meassure the area

I am already stuck at the first part of the job...My Problem is, that the edges are really sketchy. I tried some sort of prepocessing (changing the contrast and sharpness of the image) but it didn't help that much.

Does anyone has a tip where I can start to read about this type of feature detection?